# Dynamic subnet mappings for aws_lb

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a network load balancer with Terraform and it's important it is associated with elastic IPs that are protected from being destroyed.

I have code something like the following:

```
resource "aws_lb" "balancer" {
  name = "${var.name}-nlb"

  internal           = "${var.internal}"
  load_balancer_type = "network"
  subnets            = ["${data.aws_subnet_ids.selected.ids}"]

  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id     = "someid"
    allocation_id = "someid"
  }

  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id     = "someid"
    allocation_id = "someid"
  }

  subnet_mapping {
    subnet_id     = "someid"
    allocation_id = "someid"
  }

  tags = "${merge(var.tags,
    map("Terraform", "true"),
    map("Environment", var.environment))}"
}
```

What I am after is to make the `subnet_mapping` blocks dynamically as this code sits in a module and I want to create the number of mappings dependant on the amount of subnets passed in. Either that or pass in the blocks predefined.

Is there a way to do this? The important thing for me is that the elastic IPs associated need to stick around.

Comment: Do you really have a case for differing amounts of subnets? Are you running across multiple regions with varying amounts of AZs? If not you can simplify things a lot.

Comment: depends, it's a module that I am publishing to an internal repository I can't make assumptions about how others use it.

Comment: No, I can't make that assumption and it's not what I'm asking. So the real question is, is what I'm asking actually possible because if its not (you can't use count) then you are correct you can simplify this.

Comment: Then the answer is no. Terraform doesn't currently allow you to dynamically set sub resource counts.

Comment: I suspect you are right :) I'd add that as an answer it may well get accepted :)

Comment: @krystanhonour I use random_shuffle to manage dynamic subnets and I use lifecyle to ignore changes related to subnets. Again, this is tedious as you need to taint random_shuffle module again and again. That is how I manage infrastructure scattered in multiple AZ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the dynamic blocks feature from Terraform 0.12 for that.

```
resource "aws_lb" "balancer" {
  name               = "${var.name}-nlb"
  load_balancer_type = "network"

  dynamic "subnet_mapping" {
    for_each = aws_subnet.public.*.id
    content {
      subnet_id = subnet_mapping.value
      allocation_id = aws_eip.lb[subnet_mapping.key].id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: yup recently this has become a non issue going to accept this as upgrading to new shiny fixes the issue and its the cleanest solution. As was alluded to on the previous accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [Hendrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57760953/2291321) this is now doable in Terraform 0.12 by using the [`dynamic` blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#dynamic-blocks) feature:

A simpler example than the above linked answer is shown in the documentation :

```
resource "aws_security_group" "example" {
  name = "example" # can use expressions here

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.service_ports
    content {
      from_port = ingress.value
      to_port   = ingress.value
      protocol  = "tcp"
    }
  }
}
```

---

Original:

Terraform doesn't currently allow you to use the `count` meta parameter on resource stanzas/sub resources.

There is an [issue tracking this on Github](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7034) but there isn't currently any work being done on it AFAIK.

The Hashicorp employee responding in that thread ([apparentlymart](https://github.com/apparentlymart)) is currently working on a new version of HCL which may in future support something like this.

Comment: Thanks, annoying but looks I'm not the only one who needs this.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty ugly solution might be to create a resource for each of the possible numbers of AZ's. ex (code untested):

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}
resource "aws_lb" "lb_2_azs" {
    count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names) == 2 ? 1 : 0 }"
    ... all the rest of the stuff here ...
}
resource "aws_lb" "lb_3_azs" {
    count = "${length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names) == 3 ? 1 : 0 }"
    ... all the rest of the stuff here ...
}
```

And then in your module outputs something like this might work:

```
output "lb_id" {
    value = "${element(concat(aws_lb.lb_2_azs.*.id, aws_lb.lb_3_azs.*.id, list("")), 0)}"
}
```

How to handle the listener and the other resources that might be needed for the LB:

```
resource "aws_lb_listener" "listener" {
    count = "${length(concat(aws_lb.lb_2_azs.*.id, aws_lb.lb_3_azs.*.id))}"
    load_balancer_arn = "${element(concat(aws_lb.lb_2_azs.*.id, aws_lb.lb_3_azs.*.id, list("")), 0)}"
    ... rest of the resource settings ...
}
```

I haven't tested the previous code, but here's some that I know works. I have a module for consul that creates an NLB if it's not being used for vault:

```
resource "aws_lb" "consul" {
    name               = "${var.lb_name}"
    count              = "${var.for_vault ? 0 : 1}"
    internal           = true
    subnets            = ["${var.subnet_ids}"]
    load_balancer_type = "network"
    idle_timeout = 60
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "consul" {
    count             = "${var.for_vault ? 0 : 1}"
    load_balancer_arn = "${aws_lb.consul.arn}"
    port              = 8500
    protocol          = "TCP"

    default_action {
        target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.consul.arn}"
        type             = "forward"
    }
}
```

You can use the same count trick for aws_lb_target_group and any other resources you need that refer to whichever of the aws_lb resources.

Comment: How do you then handle listener rules and target groups? You need to refer to the Arn of the aws_lb resource for that and if it doesn't exist because it wasn't created by count being 0 then Terraform will error.